# Deserialize Json like { List : { [ ... ], [ ... ] } }

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

It's my first work with Json.
I've already installed Json.Net in my Visual Studio project and used to deserialize some simple string like this:

```
{
      "A":"1",
      "B":"2",
      "C":"3"
}
```

With this code:

```
JToken token = JObject.Parse("{ "A":"1","B":"2","C":"3"}";
string aValue = token.SelectToken("A");
string aValue = token.SelectToken("B");
string aValue = token.SelectToken("C");
```

But I don't know how to do with a Json like this:

```
{
     "LIST":[
          {
               "A":"value1",
               "B":"value1",
               "C":"value1"
          }
          {
               "A":"value2",
               "B":"value2",
               "C":"value2"
          }
          {
               "A":"value3",
               "B":"value3",
               "C":"value3"
          }
     ],
     "D":"value4",
     "E":"value5",
     "F":"value6"
}
```

How can get all elements of type and the other variable like D, E and F?

Thank you

Comment: For one, your JSON is invalid. You're missing commas after the objects in your array.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the array elemets are separated by commas.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way would be to create objects and deserialize into those:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Child[] LIST { get; set; }
    public string D { get; set; }
    public string E { get; set; }
    public string F { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have your classes defined, deserializing your JSON is as easy as:

```
var p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(json);
```

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure Json.NET just assigns it to anonymous types if you just use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)`

Comment: I made as indicated but the array Children is null. The other variables like d, e and f are ok.

Comment: @Yiyi In the `Parent` class above, change the name of the `Children` property to `LIST`, or, alternatively, add `[JsonProperty("LIST")]` before the `Children` property.  Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

@Justin's answer is good and will work well.  However, if you want to continue using the LINQ-to-JSON API style as you are doing now, here is how you can get all the info:

```
JToken token = JToken.Parse(jsonString);

foreach (JToken t in token["LIST"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(t["A"]);
    Console.WriteLine(t["B"]);
    Console.WriteLine(t["C"]);
}

Console.WriteLine(token["D"]);
Console.WriteLine(token["E"]);
Console.WriteLine(token["F"]);
```